# Finish another app from my application in android

Tags: android

I'm building cleaner program and I need to finish other application from my app. I'm trying this - with permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES"/>`

```
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)           
this.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
am.killBackgroundProcesses("package");
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So what have you tried? What exactly is your problem?

Comment: I need a code which can finish other opened apps from my application

Comment: Some grammar and formatting improvement